# What is the correct way of retrieving youtube videos with v3.0 for an old gdata link?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

What is the alternative url I can use to retrieve youtube videos for an user?

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/USERNAME/uploads?&v=2&max-results=10&alt=jsonc

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In V3, rather than using the username, you have to use the channel ID (since it's unique, but there's no guarantee the display name is). If you don't know the channel ID, you can get it this way:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&forUsername={username}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

(don't forget to register for an api key at console.developers.google.com!)

Once you have the channel ID, you can get those videos with the search endpoint, like this:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=viewCount&part=snippet&channelId={channel id here}&maxResults=25&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

This will order the uploaded videos by popularity. You can do order=date to have them ordered chronologically rather than by popularity if you'd rather.

There are also a lot of other parameters you can use to retrieve videos; see https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list for more details.

Comment: I have been having the same problems. This solution works great! Thanks!